# Issue with border around the button - CSS

Tags: html, css, web-applications, dhtml

I have an issue with decorating button in css:

the code in CSS file is:

```
button
{

   font-family: Tahoma;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   width: 180px;
   height: 50px;
   border:1px solid black inherit;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 0 10px;
   position: relative;
   background: url(C:/w3schools_demo/willpower/Images/button1.PNG);
}
```

After I load the page, it shows:
button with - black border and uploaded image (as I wanted),
but there is some white line between image and black border.
Look at the screenshot. How to fix/remove that line?

With regards!

[image]

Comment: which browser are you working on?

Comment: for background, instead of the image, change it to a color and then check whether the white border still appears or not.

Comment: try `border:1px solid black;` instead of `border:1px solid black inherit;`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
border-style:none;
```

most, if not all elements get default styling by the browser in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue when using buttons. A border of approx 1px appears by default on clicking them. Try adding this to your button class:

```
button {
     outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that a simple toggling of the focus button in the css can get rid of this, since buttons are automatically in focus after being clicked. And an outline is added after the focus:

`<button> Hello there </button>`

/*Css Script*/

`.button:focus { outline:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
border:1px solid black inherit;
```

to

```
border:1px solid black;
```

Remove `inherit` keyword from `border` property

Comment: Browser: IE7; outline:none (failed)

Comment: could you please upload that image you're using in the question  `C:/w3schools_demo/willpower/Images/button1.PNG`

Comment: Did you tried removing `inherit` keyword from border property?

Answer (score 0):

A problem when designing web pages is the difference of how browsers interpret the code, as they do it differently.
One way that I usually do when starting is by adding the following css to avoid any default settings provided by browsers.

```
html,body,li,ul,img,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }
```

In your case, it could be the `img` element or the `button` element missing the padding property.
It can also be that your image is simply smaller than 180px / 50px.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

for background, instead of the image, change it to a color and then check whether the white border still appears or not - Answer: i tried with Navy color, white line dissapered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
   font-family: Tahoma;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   width: 180px;
   height: 50px;
   border:1px solid black inherit;
   /* this should work if any one encounters this problem  */

   border: none;

   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 0 10px;
   position: relative;
   background: url(C:/w3schools_demo/willpower/Images/button1.PNG);
}
```